# $4ab-2-5b=0$ have no solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

$a,b$ are natural numbers .

Show that $4ab-2-5b=0$ has no solution .

By contradiction : $b(4a-5)=2$

So $4a-5=${1,2} which gives $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ ( contradiction)

So the equation has no solution !

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: What is {1,2} ?

Comment: @zoli i mean't solutions ! Or what we call ENSEMBLE in french

Comment: The proof is correct

Comment: $a\in\Bbb Q\setminus \Bbb N$. Otherwise it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essence of your proof is correct, but you've written it down in an awful fashion. Contrary to popular belief, mathematics isn't just writing down some formulae and implications. **Every** proof must contain some explaining words.

In this case, a proper proof could look like this:

Assume there is an integer solution $a, b$ to the equation. Then the equations implies $b(4a - 5) = 2$. Since $b$ is a nonnegative integer, $4a - 5$ must also be a nonnegative integer [since their product would be nonpositive otherwise]. We also note that $4a - 5$ is a divisor of $2$; But since $2$ is a prime, it only has two nonnegative divisors, namely $1$ and $2$. Neither $4a - 5 = 1$ nor $4a - 5 = 2$ has a solution over the nonnegative integers, which is a contradiction to our assumption.

Comment: @user233658 Please note you had to write $\Bbb Q\setminus\Bbb N$ in order for your proof to be correct, not $\Bbb Q$. A rational number can be an integer.